# Использование Grid(UIelement) в dll

Tags: c#, dll

Как создать list в dll?

Пытался добавлять всякие using из графического проекта (где с grid нет проблем), не помогает.

Comment: убийственный вопрос. какой grid? какой list? в каком dll? что вы вообще делать то пытаетесь?

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар сообщает, что вы забыли подключить `WindowsBase`, `PresentationCore` и `PresentationFramework`

Comment: @VladD Помогло. Огромное спасибо ))))

Comment: @VladD, просто для информации... как вам удается отвечать либо комментировать первым практически каждый вопрос? Неужели вы мониторите сайт 18 часов в сутки?

Comment: @nikita: На самом деле я экспериментальный интерфейс Skynet, наблюдаю за человечеством в 256 потоков.

Comment: @nikita _"как вам удается отвечать либо комментировать первым практически каждый вопрос?"_ -- у сайта есть API (но это не обязательно, если парсить html). можно отслеживать сообщения. и можно сделать свой UI, вместо того, чтобы отвечать через браузер. а еще можно вести свою статистику. и если приходит вопрос, от того, кто часто их задает и не забывает ставить лайки, то тому и отвечать в первую очередь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, вы не подключили сборки `WindowsBase`, `PresentationCore` и `PresentationFramework`.

Дело в том, что когда вы создаёте проект с WPF-приложением, эти сборки подключаются автоматически. А если вы создаёте просто DLL-ку, Visual Studio не знает, что вам понадобится функциональность WPF, и не подключает их сама. Поэтому их приходится подключать вручную.